# Returning XML from web API c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, formatter

newbie here as long as web API is concerned.

web Api:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement tournament = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Tournament"));
        XmlElement match = (XmlElement)tournament.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Match"));
        match.SetAttribute("ID", "SomeMatch");

        return Ok(doc.InnerXml);
    }
```

Result:

`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Tournament&gt;&lt;Match ID="SomeMatch" /&gt;&lt;/Tournament&gt;</string>`

Two problems:

1. why it is wrapped in this string element when my XML does not have it?
2. why < is converted to "& lt;" and > to "& gt;"

and how to get back just

```
<Tournament>
<Match ID="SomeMatch" /></Tournament>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are returning a string from the action, ASP.Net Web API is creating the equivalent XML to represent a string.

Now, if you were to ensure that API uses XML serialization, client can add `accept` header to the request. Alternatively, you can specify the formatter either the way you have or in the action itself by returning `Content` using following constructor:

```
return Content (HttpStatusCodeHere, doc.DocumentElement, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter)
```

Note that I do not have access to Visual Studio so class/property names might not be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to returns `doc.DocumentElement` instead of `doc.InnerXml`.

Because `doc.InnerXml` gives you xml in string format that's why your xml is shown in `<string>` format

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Test()
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement tournament = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Tournament"));
            XmlElement match = (XmlElement)tournament.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Match"));
            match.SetAttribute("ID", "SomeMatch");
            return Ok(doc.DocumentElement);                 
        }
```

All your api(s) returns output is in `xml` format because your `HttpConfiguration` set in `XmlFormatter` by default.